# Getting multiple values from Python scipy.stats ppf function

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

For my dataset I am able to fit best distribution using scipy.stats functions. For one instance best distribution is:

```
In[94]: best_dist
Out[94]: <scipy.stats._continuous_distns.chi_gen at 0x119649cd0>

In[95]: best_fit_params
Out[95]: 
(0.40982879700171049,
 0.10387428783818109,
 -4.5566762564110859e-19,
 0.89837054605455657)
```

Now I am trying to get value corresponding to 95% area of CDF curve using `ppf` function. Which gives:

```
In[96]: best_dist.ppf(0.95,best_fit_params)
Out[96]: array([ 1.44854045,  0.74815691, nan,  1.89330302])
```

I am not able to understand why there are array of length 4 is getting returned when I only expecting one value? If one of these is my answer then which is that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct usage is to unpack your `best_fit_param`:

```
In [1]: param = (0.40982879700171049,
   ...:  0.10387428783818109,
   ...:  -4.5566762564110859e-19,
   ...:  0.89837054605455657)

In [2]: from scipy.stats import beta

In [3]: beta.ppf(0.95, *param)     # notice the asterisk
Out[3]: 0.89837054605311872
```

Explanation: `beta.shapes` is `"a, b"`, so the signature of `beta.ppf` is actually `ppf(self, q, a, b, loc=0, scale=1)`. Your `best_fit_param` is a tuple of four values, for a, b, loc and scale, respectively.

I'm not sure about your `In[96]` however. In any reasonably recent scipy install calling ppf with two arguments should error out, I'd think (because it needs at least three: one for `q` and two more for `a` and `b`).